# .NET: Is there a system enum for CSS media types?

Tags: .net, css, visual-studio-2010

I notice that when I include a reference to an external CSS file in my HTML file in Visual Studio 2010, I get a very nice list of possible values for the 'media' attribute.

*(The options are all, aural, braille, handheld, print, projection, screen, tty, & tv ... if you're interested)*

**Is there a system level enum with all of the possible values for the CSS media type in .NET?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's just the intellisense XML file which gives you the valid options. As far as I know there's no enum for this in the .NET framework.